# Loading images from path generated by GET request in React

Tags: reactjs, flask, webpack, axios

I am attempting to load images in my React frontend from an array of paths that is received after a GET request to a flask backend. Initially, I tried to simply iterate over the array and require() every image, but I found out that variables cannot be required. The image paths are fetched as follows:

```
async getImages() {
    var self = this;
    await Axios.get('/getImages', { params: { number: 10, category: "front" } }
    ).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response)
      self.setState({ imagePaths: response.data.img_links, imageNames: response.data.img_names })
    }).catch(function (error) {
      alert(error);
    });

  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.getImages();
    console.log(this.state.imagePaths[0])
    this.setState({ imagesLoaded: true })


  }
```

and rendered:

```
render() {
    return this.state.imagesLoaded && this.state.imagePaths.map(item => {
        return (
            <div key={ item }>
                <img src={'./'+item} />
            </div>
        );
    })
  }
```

The above code is in Front.js, and the directory structure is as follows:

-react-frontend

--src

---components

----Front.js

----images

Every path in imagePaths is 'images/imgName.jpg'. When I get to this page in my webapp, however, the images do not load. I am wondering if this is because the images folder is in the wrong place, or I am doing something else wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check img adresses in browser dev tools, network tab

Comment: @xadm we checked, the addresses look like they should

Comment: adresses accessible by browser / public url ? full path? ... server serves static files?

Comment: all local addresses that should be accessible by browser. When I put a constant path and require() it, the image loads fine. The problem comes when I try to use the paths returned by my GET request, since I can't use require()

Comment: not by require ... only by normal html 'static'/hardcoded string src